# What does the symbol of $\mathbb{R}$ when under the integral of a probability density function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

[Image from Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUG4n.png)

What does the symbol here under the integral denote/mean with respect to the area under the function? Where does the integral actually start from?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^D } f(x) dx = 1$$

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$. Now generalize to $D$ dimensions

Comment: Also should add that what you've written doesn't really make sense unless $dx$ is short for a volume form. In coordinates it makes more sense to write something like $\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\ dx_1\ dx_2\cdots dx_n$

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in comments, the sign under the integral signs denotes "where do you do the integration" or more accurately, over what set do you do the integration..

Hence, in your case, there is some $\mathbb{R}^d$ space which is actually a tuple of $d$ elements, where each element is belong to $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $(1,0.5,\pi,..,-\sqrt\pi)$, or in a more rigorous way: $$\{(x_1,x_2,..,x_d)|x_k\in\mathbb(-\infty,\infty)\}$$

As for your second question "where does the integral actually starts from?":

I think that this is a clever question! Actually a standard definition can tell you "something" (I wont do it too formally) like the following:

The integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$ exists if and only if for every sequence of $d$ dimensional boxes that are converges to $\mathbb{R}^d$ , i.e $$E_j=Box_j\to_{t\to\infty}{\mathbb{R}^d}$$ then, $$\int_{E_j}f(x)dx\longrightarrow_{j\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$$ The idea is that the integral is defined if it *doesn't matter* how do you approach $\mathbb{R}^d$.

N.b Tried to make the explanation intuitive, there are some small points here and there that I have ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read somewhere else that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is meant to refer  to the space of n-dimensional vectors. Where does the concept of tuples come into play?

Comment: This is what I meant too, a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a collection of $n$ elements of $\mathbb{R}$. For example : every "point" in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is just a value from $(-\infty,\infty)$, and every "point" in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a pair (x,y) where $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ and also y. and the same is for any dimension.

Comment: So every "point" can be considered as a tuple